# Count the number of characters in a field (Python)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a field that contains street names and a second field called COUNT.  I need to perform a Python field calculation on the COUNT field that counts the number of characters in the STREET_NAME field.  For example if the street name is Main St then the COUNT field would be 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about via the python option in the field calculator?

1. Create the count field as Integer.
2. In the field calculator -

   len(!STREET_NAME!)

Comment: @user19300 No problem.  If one of the answers has worked for you, be sure to check it as answered.

Comment: It's not necessary to cast as string. OP isn't dealing with numerical values.

Comment: @Paul True, but I figured it was good to show for a broader use case.  For example, `len()` of an integer will fail.  I can edit if you think I should explicitly explain why?

Comment: By using single quotes around the field name you then present the `STREET_NAME` as _the_ string, so all your counts get the same value: 11 or so in this case.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for the clarification.  Better fire up Arc first next time...

Comment: @JayLaura It's just that the `STREET_NAME` field is already a `str` so it's not really needed to convert a string to a string.

Answer (score 4):

And to round things out with a cursor example...

```
import arcpy

# Create update cursor for feature class  
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(r"C:\path\to\your\featureclass") 

for row in rows:
    row.COUNT = len(row.STREET_NAME)
    rows.updateRow(row) 

# Delete cursor and row objects to remove locks on the data 
del row 
del rows
```

Comment: I thought deleting rows and cursors was unnecessary now. Can't you just do "with arcpy.UpdateCursor(...) as rows:"?

Comment: I'm not sure if the "normal" search cursor supports with statements. At least, I can't get it to work on my end. Then again, I'm not terribly familiar with normal cursors anymore now that there is the data access module.

Answer (score 3):

```python
arcpy.CalculateField_management("<file>", "COUNT", "len(!STREET_NAME!)", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

or

```python
arcpy.CalculateField_management("<file>", "COUNT", "len([STREET_NAME])", "VB")
```

Since you are dealing with street names, I'm assuming that the field is already a string.